With what vel. would you have to launch an object vertically up from the earth's surface for it to land back again at it's initial launching point?
[Can skip reading this part] First of all, Newtonian gravity shall be considered whilst trying to solve this question. It's been on my mind for a long, long time and has been bothering me since. I have come close to solving this question many times, or so I thought cause all my attempts have been proven wrong my either myself or my professors.
The question is just the title with a few extra conditions.

Negligible gravitational acc. because of the object on the earth.
Earth's rotation shall be considered and hence, the rotation of the object around the earth as well.
Therefore, the object initially has (just before the launch) both x and y component's of velocity and hence angular momentum.

So far I've only have been able to think of this question as a special case of the two-body problem. Although I don't see how I can take into consideration the relative motion of the earth spinning and the object orbiting. By that I mean the object will experience sort of a coriolis force.
Any help on understanding the motion of the object and different ways of thinking about the question will be highly appreciated.

Technically any launch will not return due to the extra forces that appear in rotating frames, so it depends on how close you can accept to initial as close enough.

Yes, the coriolis and the centrifugal force. I found a similar question to mine so I might delete this in a while. link

Being labeled as a duplicate isn't so bad though. Deleting the question negatively impacts your ability to post on this site. It is better to list duplicates even if closed as one so that future askers who might ask something similar can be lead to an explanation also.

@Triatticus Thank you for letting me know!! Yesterday I didn't quite read the solution in the question I linked, but now that I have, I realized that it is not quite what I am looking for. So either way I will keep my question up for answering.
